# Getting "GET /socket.io/?X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1677999959451-699 404 362 - 2.363 ms" requests in my express server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, httprequest, middleware

I have morgan logger middleware in my express server and it is logging some weird GET requests like
`GET /socket.io/?X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1677999959451-699 404 362 - 2.363 ms`.

I am a little new to this, so I was wondering what is the thing that is  causing this.My node_modules do not contain any socket.io module.

I have tried tracing it in the server but I am not able to find the source of this. Also, my middleware setup looks like this ->

```
//middlewares defined!
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); //static files
app.use(express.json()); //json files
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //form data parser
app.use(cookieParser()); //cookie parser

//towards router
app.use('/', authRouter);
app.use('/', userRouter);

//notFound
app.use(notFound);
```

Comment: Is your server publicy accessible? Maybe a bot...

Comment: No this was on my localhost